# Safari doesn't display multi-column layout when printing

Tags: html, css, printing, safari

I'm developing a webapp where I need to print a report.  The report has recommendations that get displayed in two columns:

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>recommendation 1</p>
  <p>recommendation 2</p>
  <p>recommendation 3</p>
  <p>recommendation 4</p>
  <!-- repeat many times -->
</div>
```

This works great in all browsers except for Safari.  Safari lays out the page correctly in the browser, but falls back to single-column layout otherwise.

What can I do to prevent this behavior and make Safari keep the multi-column layout even when printing?

NOTE: I've verified this behavior happens with the exact code above but obviously it can't be tested without pasting the code into a separate file.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, multicolumn print layout doesn't work in Safari. [See this for the proof](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15546).

For me personally, I found only one solution - use table, but that needs manual algorithm to split text into columns.